# Listing files that have a certain name and contain a certain string

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to figure out a way to write a shell script that lists file names that start and end with certain characters/digit but also contain a certain string in the file.

So say the file name has to start with a digit and end with a character, but that file also has to contain "xyz". How would I work it out so that the result is just the name of the files.

The file names should be looked for in the current directory.

I know how to get them separately but I dont know how to combine the two together to get the proper outcome.

Example: List file names:
-starting with "F" and ending with a digit.
-contains "xyz" within the file.
File1 = "xyz"
File2 = "xYz"
File3 = "xyz"
tile4 = "xyz"
File = "xyz"

Here only File1 and File3 would be listed because they meet the criteria

Comment: Can you please add a concrete example showing what you already know and also some sample files and output?

Comment: For example the file has to start with "F" but end with any digit, but the file also has to contain "xyz". Example: File1 = "xyz". File2="xYz". File3="xyz". tile4="xyz". File="xyz". In this case only File1 and File3 will be outputted because they meet the requirements @Quasímodo

Comment: Hang on. The filenames are File1 File2, etc... and the contents are xyz, correct? Making a list in the form `filenames = content`  is very confusing, but the description seems clear enough. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -l 'xyz' F*[0-9]
```

looks for xyz in every file whose name starts with "F" and ends with a digit. The `-l` swtich makes Grep suppress the matching lines and only report the matching files.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "F*[[:digit:]]" | while read line; do 
    grep -q xyz $line 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo $line 
    fi;  done
```

The above code will find files in the current directory that starts with `F` and ends with a digit. It will then loop over each file that passes the `find` criterion, and each iteration will perform `grep` in the file to find the string `xyz`. The grep output is not printed out because of `-q`. It will then check the error status of the `grep` command. If there was a match in the file, grep returns `0`, so the `echo $line` will be executed. Here, `$line` refers to the file that was found from the `find` command that has been piped into the `while` part. If `grep` returned no match, it will return `1`, so `echo $line` will not be run.

Comment: Find will look in subdirectories too. The variables should be quoted and this will unfortunately fail for weird file names. Better to use `-exec` if really going this route.